# Mobile safari only makes some pages "reader available"

Tags: wordpress, mobile, safari

I'm running a WordPress site, with a standard template for both my interior pages http://pir.org/resources/ and http://pir.org/products/. However when looking at them in my mobile safari browser on my iphone 5, only the Resources page says "Reader View Available".

They are laid out exactly with the same "article" tags for the main body content. What gives?

On the Products page, which doesn't by default have the "reader available" for Safari, it seems if i take away:

```
<ul>
<li><a title=".орг Domain" href="https://pir.org/products/opr-domain/">Russian (Cyrillic)</a></li>
<li><a title=".संगठन Domain" href="https://pir.org/products/hindi-domain/">Hindi (Devanagari)</a></li>
<li><a title=".机构 Domain" href="https://pir.org/products/chinese2char-domain/">Simplified Chinese</a></li>
</ul>
```

then the reader option becomes available. Seems as if a simple unordered list shouldn't break that feature?